# How to change the value of props of built in component using ref

Tags: react-native

```
       class Home extends Component{ 
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.opacref=React.createref()
}

 <View ref={this.opacref}style={{flex:1,opacity:0}}/>
<Button
 onpress={()=>this.opacref.current.props.style.opacity=0.5}
    title={'ok'}
   />
</View>
}
```

The above code is the blueprint of my code, my problem is I cannot able to change style value using

ref,

**What I expected:**
The opacity if the view will be changed

**What actually happened:**

throws an error null is Not object

Answer (score 0):

You could use state to update value of style.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    opacity: 0,
  }
}

<View style={{flex:1, opacity:this.state.opacity}} />
  <Button
   onpress={()=>this.setState({ opacity: 0.5 })}
    title={'ok'}
   />
</View>
```

Comment: How could you do it with using ref?

Comment: No, you can't do it